# How can I make a query force to use such an index?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT u.id, user_fname, user_lname, reputation, email, events
FROM users u
INNER JOIN cookies c ON u.id = c.user_id
WHERE c.cookie = $token
```

Also I have these indexes:

1. `cookies(cookie, user_id)` -- this is a normal index
2. `cookies(cookie)` -- this is an unique index

When I execute query above *(along with `EXPLAIN`)*, it uses the second index: `cookies(cookie)`. Well how can I make it force to use the first index? `cookies(cookie, user_id)`

Comment: Which tables are `user_fname, user_lname, reputation, email, events` in?  Please add aliases to each column used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `cookie` is a *unique* index, then there is no advantage to using the first index.  This is especially true if any of the columns in the `SELECT` come from the `cookies` table.

In any case, if the `cookie` is unique, basically the processing is:

- Look up the cookie value (really fast, using an index).
- Look up the corresponding cookie record (really fast, to fetch one page).
- Look up the corresponding record from users (really fast, using an index).

The first index might be able to eliminate the second fetch.  However, the additional information provided by the unique index probably balances this out -- and the query should be really fast either way.

Answer (score 1):

use  FORCE INDEX (your_index)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html

```
 SELECT u.id, user_fname, user_lname, reputation, email, events
 FROM users u
 INNER JOIN cookies c ON u.id = c.user_id
 FORCE INDEX (your_index) 
 WHERE c.cookie = $token
```

Comment: Oh .. `FORCE INDX` is exactly what I was looking for. thank you .. upvote

Comment: Just may you please tell me what's the difference between `FORCE` and `USE` ?

Comment: In the mysql reference you can find "The FORCE INDEX hint acts like USE INDEX (index_list), with the addition that a table scan is assumed to be very expensive. In other words, a table scan is used only if there is no way to use one of the named indexes to find rows in the table."